# npm ls minimist@0.2.1 invalid extraneous

Tags: node.js, npm, node-modules, nvm

Unable to update minimist dependency to secure version. I am trying to update package minimist to 0.2.1 and I did following changes :

```
"resolutions": {
    "minimist": "~0.2.1"
  }

"scripts":{
    "preinstall": "npx npm-force-resolutions"
}
```

npm install works fine , but `npm ls minimist`  shows:

```
myapp % npm ls minimist           


  ├─┬ babel-cli@6.26.0
│ └─┬ chokidar@1.7.0
│   └─┬ fsevents@1.1.3
│     ├── minimist@1.2.6  extraneous
│     └─┬ node-pre-gyp@0.6.39
│       ├─┬ mkdirp@0.5.1
│       │ └── minimist@1.2.6  invalid
│       └─┬ rc@1.2.1
│         └── minimist@1.2.6 
├─┬ babel-loader@7.1.5
│ └─┬ mkdirp@0.5.1
│   └── minimist@1.2.6  invalid
├─┬ grunt@1.0.1
│ ├─┬ dateformat@1.0.12
│ │ └─┬ meow@3.7.0
│ │   └── minimist@1.2.6 
│ └── minimist@1.2.6  extraneous
├─┬ karma@1.5.0
│ └─┬ optimist@0.6.1
│   └── minimist@1.2.6  invalid
├─┬ karma-mocha@1.3.0
│ └── minimist@1.2.6  invalid
├── minimist@1.2.6 
├─┬ phantomjs-prebuilt@2.1.16
│ ├─┬ extract-zip@1.6.6
│ │ └─┬ mkdirp@0.5.0
│ │   └── minimist@1.2.6  invalid
│ └── minimist@1.2.6  extraneous
├─┬ UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY webpack@3.12.0
│ └─┬ watchpack@1.6.0
│   └─┬ chokidar@2.0.4
│     └─┬ fsevents@1.2.4
│       ├── minimist@1.2.6  extraneous
│       └─┬ node-pre-gyp@0.10.0
│         ├─┬ mkdirp@0.5.1
│         │ └── minimist@1.2.6  invalid
│         └─┬ rc@1.2.7
│           └── minimist@1.2.6 
└─┬ webpack-dev-server@2.9.7
  └─┬ internal-ip@1.2.0
    └─┬ meow@3.7.0
      └── minimist@1.2.6 

npm ERR! invalid: minimist@1.2.6/Users/......./../.../node_modules/json5/node_modules/minimist
npm ERR! invalid: minimist@1.2.6 /Users/node_modules/minimist
npm ERR! invalid: minimist@1.2.6/Users/node_modules/tsconfig-paths/node_modules/minimist
npm ERR! invalid: minimist@1.2.6 /Users/node_modules/meow/node_modules/minimist
npm ERR! invalid: minimist@1.2.6/Users/node_modules/optimist/node_modules/minimist
npm ERR! invalid: minimist@1.2.6 /Users/node_modules/karma-mocha/node_modules/minimist
npm ERR! extraneous: minimist@1.2.6 /Users/node_modules/mocha/node_modules/minimist
............
............
```

Is it not possible to update dependency of dependency like this?What is the way to get this done?

Edit:

```
Package.json
{
  "name": "myapp",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "DESC",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "grunt build",
    "preinstall": "npx npm-force-resolutions"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "articatroy.url"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
 
  "babel": {
    "presets": [
      "env",
      "react",
      "stage-2"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-eslint": "^8.2.3",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.4",
    "babel-plugin-inline-json-import": "^0.2.1",
    "babel-plugin-transform-class-properties": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-plugin-transform-decorators": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy": "^1.3.4",
    "babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-react-jsx": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-preset-airbnb": "^2.4.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.1",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-mobx": "^1.0.2",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-2": "^6.24.1",
    "bundle-loader": "~0.5.5",
    "chai": "~3.5.0",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.11",
    "enzyme": "^3.3.0",
    "minimist": "^1.2.3",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.1.1",
    "eslint": "^4.19.1",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^16.1.0",
    "eslint-loader": "^2.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-babel": "^4.1.2",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.11.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.0.3",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.7.0",
    "fetch-mock": "^6.4.2",
    "file-loader": "~1.1.5",
    "grunt": "~1.0.1",
    "grunt-contrib-clean": "~1.0.0",
    "grunt-contrib-copy": "~1.0.0",
    "grunt-env": "~0.4.4",
    "grunt-karma": "~2.0.0",
    "grunt-webpack": "~2.0.1",
    "sonarqube-scanner": "2.5.0",
    "karma": "~1.5.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.2.0",
    "karma-mocha": "~1.3.0",
    "karma-mocha-reporter": "~2.2.3",
    "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "~1.0.4",
    "karma-safari-launcher": "~1.0.0",
    "karma-sourcemap-loader": "~0.3.7",
    "karma-webpack": "2.0.3",
    "load-grunt-tasks": "~3.5.2",
    "mocha": "~3.2.0",
    "phantomjs-prebuilt": "~2.1.14",
    "sinon": "^5.0.10",
    "style-loader": "^0.21.0",
    "webpack": "^3.8.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "~2.9.3",
    "uuid": "^3.3.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react/react-spectrum": "^2.21.0",
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.23.0",
    "build-url": "^1.2.0",
    "classnames": "^2.2.5",
    "es6-promise": "~4.1.0",
    "isomorphic-fetch": "^2.2.1",
    "jquery": "~3.1.1",
    "less": "^3.0.4",
    "less-loader": "^4.1.0",
    "loglevel": "^1.6.1",
    "mobx": "^4.2.0",
    "mobx-react": "^5.1.2",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "react": "^16.3.2",
    "react-dom": "^16.3.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.2.2",
    "style-loader": "^0.21.0",
    "underscore": "^1.8.3",
    "url-parse": "^1.4.0",
    "uuid": "^3.3.2",
    "minimist": "^1.2.3"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "minimist": "^1.2.3"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

resolutions is when using ymal.
for npm you should use **overrides**
https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/configuring-npm/package-json#overrides

notice you will need npm version 8.3 at least